# using data from another function in same class php

Tags: php, model-view-controller

there is just kind of pass out for me.
i had a procedural code which is working and for some this i try to deploy it in php MVC but i need your help is kind of new to me.
pls checkout this my code. and correct.
thank you soo much in advance.

```
 class Insert extends Controller
    {

         var $gender;
         var $ageR;

         function __construct()
        {
          parent::__construct();  
        }

           function xhrInsert()
        {           
          //  I want to be able to reuse the value of Post in Function below
                $gender = $_POST ['gender'];
                $ageR = explode ( ',', $_POST ['age'] );
                $this->model->xhrInsert($gender,$ageR[0],$ageR[1]);
                }

        function getReiseType()
        {
 // I need the value from $gender in function xhrInsert() here. Because i dont want to $gender = $_POST['gender']; here anymore.

            $this->model->getReiseType();
        }

    }
```

Comment: You wan to use `$gender,$ageR[0],$ageR[1]` right?

Comment: You should be able to use them (`$gender`, `$ageR`) normally in the same instance. They both are marked as protected.

Answer (score 0):

Use self::FunctionName(); to enter the function from within

Answer (score 0):

I would extract the needed data from `$_POST` in the constructor of your class and store them using class variables.

```
class Insert extends Controller {
  var $gender;
  var $ageR;    

  function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();  

    $this->gender = $_POST['gender'];
    $this->ageR = explode(',', $_POST['age']);
  }

  function xhrInsert() {           
    $this->model->xhrInsert($this->gender,$this->ageR[0],$this->ageR[1]);
  }

  function getReiseType() {
    $this->model->getReiseType();             

    // Access class properties as you like
    echo $this->gender;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanx, i did that way but got an empty values in the getReiseType function. so was thinking is wrong. but could You give me an idea why am getting empty values from the secound function?

Comment: Have you tried `echo $this->gender;` in method `__construct()`? If there is data in `$_POST['gender']` then the above code will work. Please verify `$_POST['gender']` is set.

Comment: The function xhrInsert() is getting the data to database alright. but i wanted to reuse the post data againg for other purposes in the function getReiseType() without initialising the post data 2 or more times

Comment: Use `$this->model->getReiseType($this->gender, $this->ageR);` and process data in your method `getReiseType()`.

Comment: is kind of funny to me, i did same thing but it still getting the empty values output. i debug. bt still.